# Parsing date string coming from Fitbit API

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to convert date string coming back from the Fitbit API, to an NSDate/Date object on iOS.

The date string is in the following format:

```
2017-01-21T10:39:43.000
```

The API I am using is documented here: https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/devices/, and each device comes back with a  "lastSyncTime" property in the JSON.

I've tried several different date formats that keep returning a `nil` value for the date.

```
          let formatter = DateFormatter()
//        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
//        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
//        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"
//        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"
//        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz"
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let date = formatter.date(from: lastSyncTime)
```

I've tried all these different date formats to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated here. Thanks.

Comment: I sometimes struggle with date formatters as well. A suggestion: Take your candidate formatter and use it to convert a date **to** a string and log the results. Compare it to your desired format. It can help you zero in on the differnces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formatter to parse it.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
formatter.date(from: dateString)
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Boom! That's the one! Thank you :)

Comment: Keep in mind that this interprets the date string in the user's local time zone which may or may not be correct for the API.

Comment: I dont think that the time given above "2017-01-21T10:39:43.000
", has timezone value in it.

Comment: Yeah it looks like that is the time in the user's local time zone. So interpreting it back with a UTC time zone has the effect of making it seem like it's in their local time zone.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import Foundation

let date = "2017-01-21T10:39:43.000"
let formatter = DateFormatter()

formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
let formatDate = formatter.date(from: date)

print(formatDate!)
```

> **Output:** `2017-01-21 16:39:43 +0000`